# Algorithms that run in polynomial time if P=NP

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, decision-problem, polynomial-time, p-vs-np

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Polynomial-time_algorithms), it says that that there are some algorithms that would run in polynomial time if and only if P=NP. They gave one example (without citation), but are there any others? I tried looking them up and couldn't find any.

Comment: The example in Wikipedia actually works for *any* problem in NP.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ah, I did not know that. Any algorithm specifically designed for a specific problem?

Comment: I feel like if such algorithm that is not an infinite enumeration of algorithms would be known, then the understanding of P vs NP would be much higher than it currently is.

Comment: Levin's algorithm given on Wikipedia **just accepts in poly-time**. It does **not** run in poly-time overall because it runs forever for words not in SUBET-SUM.

Comment: @Laakeri Why would that be true?

Comment: @ComFreek If P=NP then also P=coNP. That might help.

Comment: See the CSTheory posting, [If P=NP, could we obtain proofs of Goldbach's Conjecture etc.?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2800/337). The answers are quite informative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia is describing Levin's universal algorithm. This is an algorithm for verifiable problems, which is competitive with the optimal algorithm (in some sense). In particular, the exact same approach would work for *any* problem in NP, not just SUBSET-SUM.